# error LNK1104: cannot open file '...\...\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\lib.obj'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to compile some tutorial codes of PCL 1.6 but I ever received this problem error LNK1104: cannot open file '......\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\lib.obj'.  I'm using VS2010 on 64bit machine. How could I solve?

I set all proprieties of project how you can see [here](http://www.pcl-users.org/Visual-studio-2010-project-and-PCL-I-need-help-to-set-up-td3517691.html) but nothing to do for me!
Where could the problem be there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should compile Boost library before using it. After compiling Boost, make sure the missing file generated.

Comment: Sorry, but how to compile Boost library? Could you provide a detailed procedure, I am not an expert. Thanks!!